# Delete attachment with post

Tags: custom-post-types, attachments, customization

I'm trying to post a delete Link for a user so he can delete his own entries:

```
global $post;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'delete_bkroadkill', $post->ID ) )
        return;

$link = "<a href='" . wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "'>".$link."</a>";
echo $before . $link . $after;
```

How can I also delete the attachment of the post with this?

Comment: If this does not work for anybody, here is the link with solution which worked for me perfectly. https://toolset.com/forums/topic/proper-post-attachment-management-via-cred/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right hook to do this:

```
add_action('before_delete_post', 'delete_post_attachments');
function delete_post_attachments($post_id){
    global $wpdb;
    global $post_type;

    if (!$post_type == 'bkroadkill')
        return;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'attachment',
        'post_status'       => 'any',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_parent'       => $post_id
    );
    $attachments = new WP_Query($args);
    $attachment_ids = array();
    if($attachments->have_posts()) : while($attachments->have_posts()) : $attachments->the_post();
            $attachment_ids[] = get_the_id();
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    if(!empty($attachment_ids)) :
        $delete_attachments_query = $wpdb->prepare('DELETE FROM %1$s WHERE %1$s.ID IN (%2$s)', $wpdb->posts, join(',', $attachment_ids));
        $wpdb->query($delete_attachments_query);
    endif;
}
```